# model flickers when I rotate the view

Tags: interface, 3d-view, performance

In my default startup .blend file, whenever I rotate the view, the cube flickers and duplicates like there are two of them. Watch [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4uHTyhbLSxBbHBYWkJGTk1haWs) video to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: What kind of computer do you have? Your computer could be too slow to effectively run Blender.

Comment: Could be the mouse. Try swapping out your mouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been told that some Mac users have been having this problem... maybe because of graphics card...
Try downloading the latest version of Blender and also disabling the Continuous Grab option @ User Preferences > Input tab.